# What does "R0, X0, R1, X1" in the Ieee 2015 low voltage test feeder mean?

Tags: symmetrical-components

I'm looking at the Line Code downloaded from https://cmte.ieee.org/pes-testfeeders/resources/, 2015 test feeder cases, European Low Voltage Test Feeder. Here I have a screenshot of the LineCode Excel table:

[image]

What does these R1, X1, R0, and X0 mean? Someone told me they're positive and zero sequence impedance, "1" is the positive sequence, and "0" is the zero sequence. However, in a local low voltage network, is this possible that the zero sequence conductor has sometimes more than three times the impedance as large as the positive sequence conductor as shown in the last six rows? I believe the positive sequence impedance should be larger or equal to the zero sequence in LV networks as the first four row shows. Could this be human errors?

Or R1, X1 simply mean the line resistance and reactance, and R0, X0 stands for neutral?

Answer (score 2):

`R` and `X` are the resistive and the reactive components of impedance measurement:

$$
Z = R + j\ X \\
|Z|=\sqrt{R^2+X^2}
$$

> Someone told me they're positive and zero sequence impedance, "1" is the positive sequence, and "0" is the zero sequence.

That's correct. But the full definition is source impedance i.e. R0 is source resistance at zero phase sequence, or X1 is the source reactance at positive phase sequence.

> Or R1, X1 simply mean the line resistance and reactance, and R0, X0 stands for neutral?

No. Neutral has its own `RN` and `XN`. The explanation of zero, positive and negative sequences are bit detailed. I'll try my best to keep them simple.

First, have a look at phasor diagram of 3P components (voltage and current):

[image: ![enter image description here]

R, S, and T are phases and displaced by 120° w.r.t. each other.

Positive and negative sequences indicate the order of components:

- Positive sequence (or positive phase sequence): The default sequence supplied by the generator: R, S, T. Equal amplitudes and displaced by 120°.
- Negative sequence: Again, equal amplitudes and displacement by 120°. But the order is reversed: R, T, S *(It's actually again R, S, T but the phasor locations are different i.e. swap S and T in the positive sequence phasor diagram and run through R, S, T. I didn't want to put another image, sorry.)*.
- Zero sequence: Equal amplitudes but all components are in phase i.e. 0° displacement.

In simple terms, these "symmetrical" components can be used to calculate the imbalance and potentially required compensation or protective relaying in poly-phase networks *(i.e. if the network is balanced/symmetrical then there's going to be positive sequence <sup>by default</sup> components only; positive, negative and even zero-sequence components otherwise)*.

> is this possible that the zero sequence conductor has sometimes more than three times the impedance as large as the positive sequence conductor as shown in the last six rows?

Those measurements should be taken under different conditions (judging by the names on the left-most columns).